# Will a new immigrant be allowed entry in the USA if he hasn't yet payed the USCIS Immigrant Fee?

Tags: usa, immigration

People who obtain a US Immigrant Visa are required to pay a "USCIS Immigrant Fee", for Green Card processing. The official instructions recommend to pay this fee before entry to the US, so you receive the GC in minimum time. **They also mention it's possible to pay it after entering the US.**

**Could someone with a valid visa, who hasn't yet payed this fee, be denied to board on the flight to US, when going through security airport?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [got answered on travel.SE before it was put on hold there](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37985/101), so I'll copy the answer here for any expats who need the information:

> Yes, they will be allowed entry, and they will become a permanent
>   resident immediately upon entry as usual. They just won't be mailed
>   the physical plastic green card. However, their immigrant visa,
>   endorsed upon entry, serves as a green card for one year, so they will
>   still be able to prove their permanent resident status without the
>   plastic card in the short term.